# Я не знаю в чём ошибка синтаксиса

Tags: python, discord, syntax

Я соблюдал все правила синтаксиса. У меня установлен модуль дискорда. Но он выдает ошибку

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\OEM\Desktop\Бот.py", line 31
    if cmd == len('инфа') = 4 return:
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Помогите мне пожалуйста с кодом.
Вот сам код

```
elif cmd == 'инфа':
        if cmd == len('инфа') = 4 return:
        n = random.randint(0,len(numbers)-1)
        await send(numbers[n].format(user=message.author))
```

Comment: Ошибка в этом условии: `cmd == len('инфа') = 4`. Вообще не понятно, что вы хотите тут проверить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вероятно, вы хотите так:

```
if len(cmd) == 4:
         return
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Сейчас будет тест.

Comment: Теперь он не отвечает на команду(. Буду фиксить

Comment: @Zer0 что именно говорит?

Comment: Ничего, команды не робят. Сам запускается P.S: Все команды кроме инфы работают

Comment: Кстати, оффтоп, я знаю но... Ты знаеш как взять рандомное число из списка?

Comment: random.choice  посмотри .если из списка. обычно используют random.randint  и задают диапазон.  @Zer0